# How to use Astropy Kuiper test

Tags: python, normal-distribution, astropy, cdf

I want to test how close the distribution of a data set is from a Gaussian with mean=0 and variance=1.

The [kuiper](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.stats.kuiper.html) test from `astropy.stats` has a `cdf` parameter, from the documentation: "A callable to evaluate the CDF of the distribution being tested against. Will be called with a vector of all values at once. The default is a uniform distribution", but I don't know how to use this to test against a normal distribution. What if I want e.g. a normal distribution with mean 0.2 and variance 2?

So I used [kuiper_two](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.stats.kuiper_two.html), also from astropy, and created a random normal distribution. See example below.

The problem I see with this is that it depends on the number of data points I generate to compare against. If I'd have used 100 instead of 10000 data points the probability (fpp) would have raised to 43%.

I guess the question is, how do I do this properly? Also, how do I interpret the D number?

```
# create data and its cdf
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.normal(loc=0.02, scale=1.15, size=50)
data_sort = np.sort(data)
data_cdf = [x/len(data) for x in range(0, len(data))]

# create the normal data with mean 0 and variance 1
xx = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=10000)
xx_sort = np.sort(xx)
xx_cdf = [x/len(xx) for x in range(0, len(xx))]
# compute the pdf for a plot
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 50)
x_pdf = stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)

# we can see it all in a plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.hist(xx, bins=20, density=True, stacked=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.6)
plt.hist(data, density=True, stacked=True, histtype='step', lw=3)
plt.plot(x, x_pdf, lw=3, label='G($\mu=0$, $\sigma^2=1$)')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(xx_sort, xx_cdf, marker='o', ms=8, mec='green', mfc='green', ls='None')
ax2.plot(data_sort, data_cdf, marker='^', ms=8, mec='orange', mfc='orange', ls='None')

# Kuiper test
D, fpp = kuiper_two(data_sort, xx_sort)
print('#   D number =', round(D, 5))
print('#   fpp =', round(fpp, 5))
# Which resulted in:
#   D number = 0.211
#   fpp = 0.14802
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`astropy.stats.kuiper` expects as first argument a sample from the distribution you want to test, and as second argument the CDF of the distribution you want to test against.

This variable is a `Callable` and expects itself (a) sample(s) for which to return the value(s) under the cumulative distribution function. You can use `scipy.stat`'s CDFs for that. By using `functools.partial` we can set any parameters.

```python
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm
from astropy.stats import kuiper

from functools import partial
from random import shuffle

np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.normal(loc=0.02, scale=1.15, size=50)

print(kuiper(data, partial(norm.cdf, loc=0.2, scale=2.0)))

# Output: (0.2252118027033838, 0.08776036566607946)

# The data does not have to be sorted, in case you wondered:
shuffle(data)

print(kuiper(data, partial(norm.cdf, loc=0.2, scale=2.0)))

# Output: (0.2252118027033838, 0.08776036566607946)
```

In this diagram from [the Wikipedia article about this test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_test), you get an idea what the Kuiper statistic V measures:

[[image: Lucas(CA), CC BY-SA 4.0 <https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0>, via Wikimedia Commons]][3](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KuiperTestVisualization_2Sample.png)
The

If you share the parameters of the comparison distribution, the distance is lower and the estimated probability that the respective underlying CDFs are identical rises:

```python
print(kuiper(data, partial(norm.cdf, loc=0.02, scale=1.15)))

# Output: (0.14926352419821276, 0.68365004302431)
```

The function `astropy.stats.kuiper_two` in contrast, expects *two* samples of empirical data to compare with one another. So if you want to compare to a distribution with a tractable CDF, it is preferable to use the CDF directly (with `kuiper`) instead of sampling from the comparison distribution (and using `kuiper_two`).

And one nit-pick. Apart from using CDF in variable names that are not a CDF, this formulation is much more readable than the above:

```python
data_cdf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, len(data), endpoint=False)
xx_cdf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, len(xx), endpoint=False)
```